# line 43: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: unix, syntax, compilation

I am getting a syntax error on line 43 when compiling the unix script code. This code is to search through a folder of textfile and match any word from the input.txt. 
code still hasn't finish yet though

```
#!/bin/bash

findkeyword () {
    file="$1"   
    keyword="$2"    
    value="$3"
    int count = 0
    cat $file | awk '{
    while read line
        do
            for (ii=1;ii<=NF;ii++) {
                if ($ii == $keyword)
                    count++
            fi
            }
        done
    }'
    echo "Profile: " $file
    scorefile $value $count

scorefile () {
    value="$1"
    count="$2"

    echo "Score: " $value*$count

}

cat input.txt | awk '{
    while read line
        do
            keyword=$1
            value=$2

            for xx in `ls submissions/*`
            do
                filename=$xx
                findkeyword $filename $keyword $value
            done
        done
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

findkeyword () {
  file="$1"   
  keyword="$2"    
  value="$3"
  int count = 0
  while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        if [[ $word =  $keyword ]]; then
            $((count++))
        fi
    done
    done <$file
  echo "Profile: " $file
  scorefile $value $count
} # missing closing brace here

scorefile () {
  value="$1"
  count="$2"

  echo "Score: " $(($value*$count)) # Math evaluation broken

}

while read line
    do
        keyword=$1
        value=$2

        for xx in `ls submissions/*`
        do
            filename=$xx
            findkeyword $filename $keyword $value
        done
    done<input.txt
```

Comment: you have a horrible munge of bash and awk in the script, this is the fundamental problem.

Comment: This bit:     cat $file | awk '{
    while read line
        do
            for (ii=1;ii<=NF;ii++) {
                if ($ii == $keyword)
                    count++
            fi
            }
        done
    }' also suffers from the same mixed bash/awk syntax

Comment: your scorefile caclulation: $value*$count won't work (you need to use $((value * count))

Comment: and you're missing the closing curly brace for the findkeyword function